# How do I bulk archive multiple messages, voicemails, or phone calls in Google Voice?

Tags: sms, archive, message, google-voice, voicemail

Exactly as the question states - how do I bulk archive messages, voicemails, and phone calls in Google Voice?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, so here you go!

- Go to https://voice.google.com
- Navigate to the section you want to archive (calls, messages, or voicemails)
- Click on the circle icon next to the first message you want to archive. Notice that when you hover over the item, the circle changes to a gray checkmark.  When you click it, it changes to a blue checkmark and a blue banner will appear saying '1 item selected'.
- Now Shift+Click the last message you want to archive.  It will select the whole group between the first and the last.  If you're archiving non-sequential items, simply click the icons of the remaining messages you want to archive (note: there is a 200 item selection limit).
- Lastly, click the archive icon in the right side of the blue 'X item(s) selected' banner.

Done!